# Cannot launch Windriver Workbench after upgrade to 14.04

Tags: linux, eclipse, java, vxworks

I upgraded to `14.04`, confirmed following required packages are still loaded:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386
sudo apt-get install libxtst-dev
sudo apt-get install libxtst-dev:i386
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-murrine:i386
sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
sudo apt-get install libxpm4:i386
sudo apt-get install libuuid1:i386
```

and upgraded to `openjdk-7-jre` as required but still, my WindRiver Workbench won't launch, I get a log file with following contents:

```
$ cat /home/ron/.workbench-3.3.6.20151117-1158_1293174511/configuration/1507498335384.log
!SESSION 2017-10-08 14:32:14.945 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20130131-0800/WB20151117-1158
java.version=1.6.0_21
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86, WS=gtk, NL=en_CA
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-10-08 14:32:16.361
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons:
        /home/ron/.workbench-3.3.6.20151117-1158_1293174511/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/466/1/.cp/libswt-pi-gtk-3836.so: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
        no swt-pi-gtk in java.library.path
        /home/ron/.swt/lib/linux/x86/libswt-pi-gtk-3836.so: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
        Can't load library: /home/ron/.swt/lib/linux/x86/libswt-pi-gtk.so

        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:331)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Library.java:240)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.<clinit>(OS.java:22)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Converter.java:63)
        at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Converter.wcsToMbcs(Converter.java:54)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:133)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createDisplay(Workbench.java:695)
        at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createDisplay(PlatformUI.java:161)
        at com.windriver.ide.application.CopyOfIDEApplication.createDisplay(CopyOfIDEApplication.java:190)
        at com.windriver.ide.application.CopyOfIDEApplication.start(CopyOfIDEApplication.java:115)
        at com.windriver.ide.application.UnifiedSWTSwingApplication.access$2(UnifiedSWTSwingApplication.java:1)
        at com.windriver.ide.application.UnifiedSWTSwingApplication.start(UnifiedSWTSwingApplication.java:70)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.WRWBMain.main(WRWBMain.java:37)
```

How may I be able to fix this so that I can re-launch Workbench?

Comment: `java.version=1.6.0_21` is used, not the Java 7 JDK; check the file permission of the *.so files mentioned in the log file; consider updating your WindRiver Workbench

Comment: @howlger yeah, that version indicator is wrong, `$ java -version` gives me: `java version "1.7.0_151"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.11) (7u151-2.6.11-1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.151-b01, mixed mode)`

Comment: Does your ini file contain the line `-vm`? https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM

Comment: @howlger the permission of `libswt-pi-gtk-3836.so` looks fine but `/home/ron/.swt/lib/linux/x86/libswt-pi-gtk.so` doesn't even exist...